# How do I filter my log file based on categories with .NET Core logging?

Tags: logging, .net-core, serilog

I've configured my logger factory like so,

```
loggerFactory
    .AddConsole()
    .AddDebug()
    .AddFile("Logs/trace-{Date}.txt");
```

and in my constructors I take dependencies on e.g. `ILogger<MyServiceClass>`. It is my understanding that the framework will then create a logger instance for my service class, with a category name based on the full name of the type.

In my log file, I see messages like this:

> 2017-07-07T09:10:46.5678506+02:00 0HL650T1MS1RU [WRN] Socket registration failed for participant b943174e-8022-4e33-ef0d-08d4c4bc4879 in negotiation 42d9720f-32a2-46f9-9042-08d4c4bc4881. (799c4f21)

I seem to remember reading somewhere that the category is hashed to save on file size, so I suspect the mouthful between the timestamp and the log level (`0HL...1RU`) represents the category, but that's not really searchable or discoverable.

How do I configure my logger to not obfuscate the category names in the log file?

Answer (score 2):

According to the code, you use [Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging-file) (the concrete logger implementation is important). That funny string `0HL...1RU` actually is a unique Request Id. I guess this logger doesn't support log categories for the plain text logs.

Workaround #1: use JSON logs:

```
loggerFactory.AddFile("filename", isJson: true);
```

`SourceContext` property will appear in the log output having your log category:

```
"SourceContext":"MyNamespace.MyServiceClass"
```

Workaround #2: just use another [third-party file logger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging#third-party-logging-providers) like NLog or full standalone [Serilog API](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging-file#using-the-full-serilog-api).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the log category by using `{SourceContext}` in the `outputTemplate`, like so:

```
loggerFactory
    .AddConsole()
    .AddDebug()
    .AddFile(
        "Logs/trace-{Date}.txt",
        , outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:o} {RequestId,13} [{Level:u3}] {SourceContext} {Message} ({EventId:x8}){NewLine}{Exception}"
    );
```